# When to eject React-Native app

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm beginning working on a React-Native app and I used the `create-react-native` cli to get started and have been messing around with basics and testing using Expo.

But I want to get actually started on things so I'm wondering if I need to eject first or if I can essentially develop the entire app and then eject it at the end and deploy to play store and apple store?

The app is pretty simple, just a couple of forms but it will also utilize the camera and files on the device, can I do that without ejecting to keep things cleaner for now? Or not really

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't eject unless there's a plugin you can't escape to use. 
You can't use the plugins who requires a `react-native link`. According to your small description, you shoulnd't detach (eject) and shouldn't need to.

For more informations about why detach or not, you can read [this page on expo doc](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/detach).

```
You might want to detach if:

Your Expo project needs a native module that Expo doesn't currently support. 
We're always expanding the Expo SDK, so we hope this is never the case. But it 
happens, especially if your app has very specific and uncommon native demands.
```

Most of the time, you will be able to use plugins / modules without link.

Comment: Thanks, I was asking because I am trying to use this camera package (https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker#usage) and it looks like it needs you to change settings in ios and android.

Don't think theres a camera package that wont require link but I'll look around some more

Comment: Feel free to use https://docs.expo.io/versions/v28.0.0/sdk/imagepicker. I'm using it in my production app, works well.

Comment: Also, I thought in order to package for deployment to the playstore / apple store (not expo), you needed to eject?

Comment: You really should take a look at expo documentation ^^. Here's the link to build native packages https://docs.expo.io/versions/v28.0.0/distribution/building-standalone-apps

Comment: You should only eject if you need to use a package that uses native code. If it's just JavaScript then you're fine. It is also non-reversible once you do it.